# $dy/dt$ = 0.8y with y(0) = -0.8 , why does the result of this question end up being so different from the formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

So I'm given a dynamic system $dy/dt$ = 0.8t with y$_0$ = -0.8.

So the Theorem in the book I'm studying says $dx/dt$ = kx
With initial value x$_0$ and k being an ordinary constant.

x is just an arbitrary variable, surely I can bring this principle to 'y' as well, right?

The solution is then $e^{kt}$$x_0$

The understanding is that x will grow or decay exponentially.

The answer I originally got with this understanding was ${-0.8}$$e^{0.8t}$.
Seems simple enough, right? Except that was not the answer. I went online and found the answer, but I do not understand how or why we come to that conclusion and ditch the theorem.

The answer I found was actually $0.4t^2$+C

C being -0.8.
And the final answer being $0.4t^2$ - 0.8.

Why do we end up doing this instead of the theorem I brought up earlier? And with this being used as a tool obviously being Integration. When do I draw the line between using an Integration or an Exponential?

Can I use Integration instead of Exponentials?

Comment: Was the equation $\frac {dy}{dt} = 0.8y$ or was it $\frac {dy}{dt} = 0.8t$?   The first is a differential equation were a function, $y$, is a scalar multiple of its derivative (which means the function is an exponential one).  The second is a simple antiderivative (integration) problem.  (See Eevee Trainer's answer).  The solution to $\frac {dy}{dt}=0.8y$ is $y = e^{0.8}y_0=-0.8e^{0.8}y$.  The solution to $\frac {dy}{dt}=0.8t$ is $\frac {0.8}2 t^2 + C$ and as $y(0)=-0.8$ then $C=-0.8$ and $y = 0.4t + C$..  But those are *entirely* different questions.

Comment: Yes you're right. I was misreading the page. The question I'm currently looking at is $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.8t $$ The question AFTER this one is $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.8y$$

Comment: So... are you satisfied with Eevee Trainer's answer? $\frac {d\ function}{d\ input\ variable} = k\ function\ itself$ has the solution $function = e^{k\ input\ variable}initial\ value$.  But $\frac {d\ function}{d\ input\ variable}=\ some \ other \ function \ with \ the \ same \ input \ variable$ has the solution $function=\int \ other\  function d\ input\ variable + Initial\ Value$.  There are different context where a derivative involves the function itself, and when the derivative is involves an independent *other* function.

Comment: Yup, already confirmed it. Thanks for breaking that down further, I'm going to write that down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful with the variables and functions.

The differential equation you which to solve is given by

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = 0.8 y(t)$$

and has solution given by (with $y_0 = y(0) = -0.8$)

$$y(t) = -0.8 e^{0.8t}$$

The solution you propose is, however (ignoring initial conditions)

$$y(t) = 0.4t^2 + C$$

Your solution makes sense if the differential equation is

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = 0.8 t$$

You need to be very careful about the difference between the two.

Comment: Okay, first. There is NOTHING about your name that I do not love with every fiber of my being.

Comment: Second , there is a  little hiccup. The question was actually $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.8t.$$ The question AFTER the one I'm solving is $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.8y.$$

Comment: But I think I understand where I went wrong. Since the left hand side has $$\frac {dy}{dt}$$ and the right hand side is 0.8t instead of 0.8y, we have to integrate to find out the answer with respect to t, right?

Comment: Essentially, yeah!

Comment: Think of it this way; $\frac {df(x)}{dx}=g(x)$ has as solution that $f(x) = G(x) + C$ where $G(x)$ is the antiderivative for $g(x)$. That's easy.  But if you have $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = k\cdot f(x)$ you have to figure that $f$ is somehow related to its own antiderivative which you can't solve as you don't know what $f$ was in the first place! But knowing $\frac {d(Ae^x)}{dx}=Ae^x$ and those are the *only* functions that are their own derivative/antiderivatives you can figure if $\frac {df(x)}{dx}= cf(x)$ then we must have $f(x) = e^{cx}\cdot K$. And by the additive nature of exponents, $K=f(0)$.